# How to install ruby 2.3 on Oracle Linux 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, oraclelinux

How to install ruby 2.3 on Oracle Linux 7 without RVM?
I don't want using rvm or build from source.

Comment: To install historical versions you'll often need to use RVM or another tool like [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). This is a common pattern as seen with other tools like Python and Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

rbenv might work for your purposes.

[README for rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/master/README.md)

[Tutorial on installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04)